# dll classes can't access in app_code folder files

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]  I am working on asp.net(3.5)
  in my project there is one layer named app_code contain the business logic of the project

in this project I have added one reference file  named *Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data*

when I include namespace in *default.aspx.cs* file it works properly but when I work on the       business logic class file which is in *app_code* folder I show compile time error.

I have not find any solution
  please give solution....

thanks in advance....

Comment: Is this a "web site" project-type, or a "web application project" type?

Comment: Can you add more information about the solution structure? A screenshot of the solution explorer will help us a lot.

Comment: i have added screenshot just see it

Comment: @vipul web application projects *don't use* `App_Code` (or at least, it doesn't have the significance it does for "web site" types) - are you sure it is that?

Comment: @vipul that screenshot **does not show** the solution explorer. Except as a collapsed tab on the right/.

Answer (score 0):

add reference to that dll in your files like `using <dllname>`

Comment: the `using` directive relates to *namespaces* (not "dllname"), and does not add a *reference*

Comment: i have already used that  but it not display the Application option of microsoft  ther are only Contracts,CSharp,Internal,SQLServer,VisualBasic and Win32